# Allocate memory for 2D array with minimum number of malloc calls

Tags: c, malloc, runtime-error

I am using the below code snippet to allocate memory for 2D array using minimum number of `malloc()` calls.

I want to access the array using subscripts, p[i][j].

```
#define ROW 3
#define COL 2

int main()
{
    void **ptr = malloc( ROW*COL* sizeof(int) );

    int (*p)[COL] = ptr;

    int i, j;

    for( i = 0; i < ROW; ++i )
            for( j = 0; j < COL; ++j )
                    scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j]);

    for( i = 0; i < ROW; ++i )
    {
            for( j = 0; j < COL; ++j )
                    printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program is outputting correctly whatever is the input.

But, it is showing  [Runtime error](http://ideone.com/t1nlL)  . Why?

Comment: No, you're seeing the input. The program isn't outputting anything.

Comment: Shouldn't the `scanf` input read into `p`, not `ptr`?

Comment: Yeah, got it. I am feeling sleepy. My bad.

Comment: Disregard my old comment about mixed-up indices. I was wrong. Indices are fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the array dimensions are known at compile-time (as in your example), then you can indeed allocate memory in one `malloc` call. But you have to use the proper pointer type to access that memory. In your case that would be your `p` pointer. You `p` pointer is declared correctly, but you for some reason are completely ignoring its existence in `scanf` and using `ptr` instead.

Stop trying to use `ptr` for array access. Use `p`. Access your array elements as `p[i][j]` and it should work.

In fact, I would get rid of `ptr` entirely and do memory allocation in the following way

```
int (*p)[COL] = malloc(ROW * sizeof *p);
```

Moreover, since *both* dimensions are known at compile time, you can actually allocate it as

```
int (*p)[ROW][COL] = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

but in this case you'll have to remember to access the array as `(*p)[i][j]` (note the `*`). Choose whichever method you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#define ROW 3
#define COL 2

int main()
{
    int *ptr = (int*)malloc( ROW*COL* sizeof(int) );

    int *p[COL];
    int i, j;

    fot (i = 0; i < COL; i++)
        p[i] = ptr + ROW * i;

    for( i = 0; i < ROW; ++i )
        for( j = 0; j < COL; ++j )
            scanf("%d", &p[i][j]);

    for( i = 0; i < ROW; ++i )
    {
            for( j = 0; j < COL; ++j )
                    printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
    }

    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Er... You are trying to access `p[i]` through a completely uninitialized pointer `p`. This will simply crash (at best).

Comment: I am initializing the array of pointers 'p' in the first loop

Comment: You cannot initialize anything, because you don't have the array yet. You `p` is declared as `int (*p)[COL]`. This declaration creates an *pointer to an array* (not an "array or pointers" as you incorrectly believe). This pointer is not initialized, i.e. it points to nowhere. And you are trying to apply `[]` operator to a pointer that points to nowhere. As I said above, this will crash hopelessly. Try it.

Comment: I will try it and if it is wrong I will correct/delete this answer.

Comment: If you wanted to declare an "array of pointers", you should have used `int *p[COL]` (note: no braces). With braces `int (*p)[COL]` it declares `p` as *pointer to array*, not *array of pointers*.