# If void** pointer is type casted into a "pointer to a COL size integer array" then its behavior should change and behave like 2D array?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allocate memory for 2D array with minimum number of malloc calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133832/allocate-memory-for-2d-array-with-minimum-number-of-malloc-calls)

As far my knowledge of concern in C void pointer is automatically converted into appropriated data type. Below is the program in which I found the warning:

> initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

```
#define ROW 3
#define COL 2

int main()
{

        void **ptr = malloc( ROW*COL* sizeof(int) );

        int (*p)[COL] = ptr;

        int i, j;

        for( i = 0; i < ROW; ++i )
                for( j = 0; j < COL; ++j )
                        scanf("%d", &p[i][j]);

        for( i = 0; i < ROW; ++i )
        {
                for( j = 0; j < COL; ++j )
                        printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
                printf("\n");
        }
        free(ptr);
        return 0;
}
```

but it worked perfectly. If `void**` pointer is type casted into a "pointer to a COL size integer array" then it's behavior should change and behave like 2D array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133832/allocate-memory-for-2d-array-with-minimum-number-of-malloc-calls

Comment: pointers to pointers and 2-dimensional arrays are completely different beasts. They are not compatible. And so `void**` is something completely different from what you want. You want an untyped data pointer, so use `void*` and not `void**`.

Comment: And as used here, the use of the variable `ptr` is superfluous. Just initialize `p` with `malloc` and use `free(p)` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `void **` pointer is not a `void *` pointer. `void **` and `void *` are two completely different types. Whatever conversion properties apply to `void *` don't apply to your `ptr`. Your initialization is indeed invalid, as compiler told you in the warning message.

Secondly, there's absolutely no need for a `void **` pointer in your program. Where did it come form anyway? If you wanted to have an "intermediate" pointer `ptr` in your program, you should have declared it with `void *` type

```
void *ptr = malloc(ROW * COL * sizeof(int));
int (*p)[COL] = ptr;
```

and the warning would disappear. However, as I said in my previous answer, there's no real need for any intermediate pointer in this case. You can just do

```
int (*p)[COL] = malloc(ROW * sizeof *p);
```

Comment: As far my knowledge of concern int (*p)[COL] means "pointer to a COL size integer array"  and void *ptr is a pointer .                         Is it relevant to equate it?

Comment: @aakasha: Well, as you correctly said yourself at the beginning of your question, a `void *` pointer can be implicitly converted to *any* other data pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

You can *assign* a  pointer to `void` pointer to any pointer. However, you assign a pointer to void pointer: that is something different.